# Error deserializing IEnumerable<byte> properties with json.net 6.0.3

Tags: json.net

Given the following class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Enumerables
{
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<Byte> ByteMember { get; set; }
}
```

And an instance initialized as:

```
var bytes = new byte[] { ... };
var o = new Enumerables { ByteMember = bytes };
```

Serialization produces this:

```
{"ByteMember": "<<base-64-encoded-string>>"}
```

But this string cannot be deserialized. The error produced is:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException : Error converting value
"vbMBTToz9gyZj6gZuA59rE7ryu3fCfimjVMn8R6A0277Xs9u" to
type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Byte]'.
Path 'ByteMember', line 1, position 8084.
----> System.ArgumentException : Could not cast or convert from
System.String to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Byte].
```

I don't see this happening for `byte[]`, `List<byte>` or `Collection<byte>` properties, which are correctly serialized to and from base-64 strings. And I don't see this happening for any `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is not a byte -- for example, a property of type `IEnumerable<int>` deserializes to a `List<double>`, an effective implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How an `IEnumerable<byte>` gets serialized depends on the *concrete* type that is assigned to it.  If the concrete type is a `byte[]` then it will get serialized specially as a base-64 encoded string, whereas if it is some other concrete type like a `List<byte>`, it will be serialized as a normal array of numbers.  The same is true of `ICollection<byte>` and `IList<byte>`.  ([DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cq59ID))

On deserialization, Json.Net looks at the types of the member properties of the target class to determine what types of objects to create.  When the member property is a concrete type, no problem; it creates an instance of that type and tries to populate it from the JSON.  If the member type is an interface, then Json.Net has to make a guess, or throw an error.  You could argue that Json.Net should be smart enough to guess that if the member variable is an `IEnumerable<byte>` and the JSON value is a base-64 encoded string, it should convert the string to a `byte[]`.  But that is not how it is implemented.  In fact, the special handling for base-64 encoded byte arrays is only triggered if the member property is `byte[]` specifically.  With no special handling for `IEnumerable<byte>`, this results in an error because a `string` can't be assigned directly to an `IEnumerable<byte>`.  Again, the same is true for `ICollection<byte>` or `IList<byte>`.
([DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3VsLK1))

If you want it to work the same for types implementing `IEnumerable<byte>` as it does for `byte[]`, you can make a custom `JsonConveter` like this:

```
public class EnumerableByteConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(IEnumerable<byte>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        byte[] bytes = ((IEnumerable<byte>)value).ToArray();
        writer.WriteValue(Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(reader.Value.ToString());
        if (objectType == typeof(byte[]))
        {
            return bytes;
        }
        return new List<byte>(bytes);
    }
}
```

To use the converter, create an instance of `JsonSerializerSettings` and add an instance of the converter to the `Converters` collection.  Then, pass the settings to `SerializerObject()` and `DeserializeObject()` methods.  For example:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Converters.Add(new EnumerableByteConverter());

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);
```

Here is a [working round-trip demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gyqNvW).  Note, however, that this converter doesn't (and can't) handle every possible `IEnumerable<byte>` that might be out there.  For example, it won't work with `ISet<byte>` as currently implemented.  If you need support for this or other additional types, you will need to extend the `ReadJson` method to handle that.  I leave this to you.